# How do I fire an event handler in a separate thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, event-handling

I've created a service which will fire an event for each of the item in the list.
I've used a foreach loop to iterate through the list and trigger the event for each of the item in the list.
In order to improve the performance of the service,
It was suggested that i try to run the event handler in a separate thread.
I'm new to the concept of threading,
Can I get some suggestions on how I can run only the event handler on a separate thread? Should I create a separate thread for the each of the item in my list?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Here is my code:

```
public void UpdateMessages(){

foreach(var message in messages)
{
    message.Received += 
TextMessage_MessageReceived;

}
```

}

```
private void RawMessage_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs<TextMessage> e)
{
    var msgText = sender as RealtimeTextMessage;
   RawMessageList[msgText].SetMessageBytes(msgText);
}
```

In the code snippet I have the event handler RawMessage_MessageReceived which will perform the operation of extracting the bytes from the raw message.
I need to perform the event handling in a different thread since from what I understand about threading, a single thread will be responsible for raising the event for each message and simultaneously will be responsible for event handling of each event.
How can I write a separate thread to take care of the event handling part?

Comment: try using `Parallel.Foreach` , for usage have a look on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

Comment: How to create a threading model (ie: *Should I create a separate thread for the each of the item in my list?)* is a design decision.  It cannot be made with the information you've provided.  It depends entirely on what these handlers will be doing.  Maybe one thread is the right answer.  Maybe a pool is the answer.  Maybe one thread per event is the answer.  We can't know without a full understanding of what your project is doing.

Comment: How are you intending to use these events? Who is going to subscribe to them?

Comment: _"It was suggested that i try to run the event subscription in a separate thread."_ - make sure you got that right. It doesn't make sense. Did they mean "event **handling**"?

Comment: @Fildor yes, I meant to say event handling. I haveedited the question to make it more understandable. I have included an example code snippet. Let me know your inputs

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have edited the question details and added a code snippet with the details of the event handler.

Comment: My inputs ... let's see. It is somewhat surprising to me that `message` has an event "Received". I would expect a "Message" class to be a somewhat "dumb" object to pass around data.

Comment: you can leverage Task Parallel Library API. The TPL is a set of software APIs in the System.Threading.Tasks namespace of .NET. It was originally introduced with version 4.0 of the .NET Framework..